# Cannot run Live USB, kernel panic in ThinkPad E560

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, thinkpad

I tried to install `Ubuntu` in `Lenovo Thinkpad 560` but every time it's shows `kernel panic`. Version I tried are `Ubuntu 17.04, 14.04.1`, `Fedora 25 (all 32bit)`. Cannot start the live desktop mode either.

Options I tried are following:

```
1. nomodeset
2. intel_pstate=no_hwp
3. intel_pstate=disable
4. multiple USB flash drive
5. multiple application to create USB bootable flash drive
6. UEFI
7. Legacy
8. Run memory test, and passed
```

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that the Ubuntu ISO you downloaded was not corrupted?

Comment: I suggest that you try 64-bit operating systems in this laptop. And I suggest that you **clone** the iso file to a USB pendrive, and try booting from it. It *should* work with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS amd64 (alias 64-bit). Please check with md5sum, that the iso file is good. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/927268/cant-boot-from-usb-drive-after-copying-iso-with-dd/927299#927299

Comment: last time i tried to boot and something similar happened it was a corrupted disk image. try redownloading the iso and burning it to your disk with different tools.

Comment: 64bit fixed the issue. I was surprised! why 32 bit version didn't work ?