# dd doesn't work

Tags: usb-drive, dd, disk-image

I do

```
$ df -h
...
/dev/sdc1       1,5G  1,5G     0 100% /media/username/Ubuntu 17.04 amd64

$ umount /dev/sdc1

$ df -h
...
#sdc1 now not listed

$ sudo dd if=./memtest86-usb.img of=sdc
307200+0 records in
307200+0 records out
157286400 bytes (157 MB, 150 MiB) copied, 2,78627 s, 56,5 MB/s
```

but flashdrive remain unchanged.

what is wrong?

Comment: @user68186 read the hover text on the downvote arrow. It doesn't say anything about whether something is a "common mistake".

Comment: `df` only lists mounted partitions, so of course it would not show up in the output after unmounting.

Comment: Also, when writing image to a disk, it's often necessary to specify the block size, something like `bs=4M`. Also makes `dd` run a bit faster, iirc

Comment: You should be more careful when typing `dd` commands. That you make a mistake at all is an indication that you are not giving `dd` the respect it deserves. There's a reason seasoned *nix folks call it `disk destroyer`.

Comment: @user68186 what was your point? Common mistakes shouldn't be downvoted? On the contrary, common mistakes are the ones most eligible for downvoting, because the downvoting tooltip says: "This question does not show any reasearch effort", and if it were indeed that common, basic research would have uncovered the mistake.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, It is a good idea to specify the block size, `bs=4096` or more will make the [cloning  with `dd` faster](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931581/flashing-ubuntu-iso-to-usb-stick-with-dd/931588#931588) than with the default block size (`bs=512` ). But I would not say that it is necessary.

Comment: @sudodus It's not required usually, but I think with Raspberry Pi I had couple times when image wouldn't load properly without the flag. But yeah, not a requirement

Comment: @muru withdrawn.

Answer (score 31):

Your command creates a file named `sdc` in the current directory. You want `of=/dev/sdc`.

So the complete correct command is:

```
sudo dd if=./memtest86-usb.img of=/dev/sdc
```

Run `sync` afterwards to synchronize cached writes to disk or use the `conv=fsync` option with `dd`.

Comment: Note that you'll also want to `sync` after `dd` but before removing the flash drive.

Comment: (or use the `conv=fsync` option with `dd`)

Comment: @muru I think `oflag=sync` would be more equivalent to a single `sync` command run afterwards?

Comment: @detly the way I understand it, `oflag=sync` forces *every* write to be synchronized, but `conv=fsync` forces synchronization only at the end. So the former would have more consistent write speeds, perhaps, but the latter is more like a `sync` command run afterwards.

Comment: @muru Ah you're right, I had it completely backwards.

Answer (score 6):

I support @RoVo's answer - it is a correct and good answer to the question.

---

I would like to add that `dd` is risky, and has caused problems for many users, because it will do what you tell it to do without any question. A minor typing error can make it overwrite an internal drive or a backup drive with important files.

You can play safer by using a [cloning] tool with a **final checkpoint**, that will give you a second chance to double-check and also display information about the available target devices.

- **Disks** alias `gnome-disks`
- **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**

Link with more details: [Cloning tools with a final checkpoint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042167/is-there-a-specific-format-a-usb-needs-to-be-to-boot-from/1042172#1042172)