# I'm trying to burn an ISO to a thumb drive

Tags: iso

I tried this using a terminal with the disk dump command. After everything was done the thumb drive appears to have everything there. But I'm trying to go from Ubuntu 14.4 32x to Ubuntu 18.4 64x and it is not booting. Can someone please help?

Comment: you have to use the usb maker...are you using ubuntu to create the disk? if so use startup disk creator

Comment: See this link, [Can't boot from USB drive after copying iso with dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927268/cant-boot-from-usb-drive-after-copying-iso-with-dd/927299#927299)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot from USB drive after copying iso with dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927268/cant-boot-from-usb-drive-after-copying-iso-with-dd) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already in Ubuntu, use "startup disk creator" to make your install media.

From activities window search "startup" and click startup disk creator.

From this window you simply click the "other" button and browse to your ISO. Then select your thumb drive in "Disk to Use" and click make startup disk.

Using dd doesn't work for some reason.

There is a great tutorial here:

[How To Create A Bootable Live USB](https://www.tutonics.com/2012/06/how-to-create-bootable-live-usb.html)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i get an error when trying to boot. so i went downloaded the file from ubuntu website instead of a torrent. put that iso on my drive and its still not working?